# what is the meaning of "vector" in the context of algorithms?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

I'm familiar with the concept of vectors in math and physics, but this wording in a computer science textbook is unfamiliar to me.

> A configuration in the shared memory model is a vector
>
> $$C=(q_0,\dots, q_{n-1}, r_0,\dots, r_{m-1}) $$

Comment: You may also know this as an *array*. And watch out what they call vector in microbioligy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This use of "vector" just means something with a number of components, in a specific order.  Mathematicians would usually call it a (finite) sequence.

Comment: I'd call it a tuple.

Comment: I think I like tuple in this context too...